# undefined method `layout' for #<WelcomeController:0x00000006ab2df8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, layout, controller

I want my welcome controller to use a different layout:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    if signed_in?
      layout 'default'
    else
      layout 'welcome'
    end
    render 'welcome/index'
  end

end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    if signed_in?
      render :layout => 'default'
    else
      render :layout => 'welcome'
    end
  end

end
```